# Double if statement then highlight if value <> to % of

Tags: vba, excel

What im trying to do is: If a cell on Column D says cars then check the last cell on the right (last cell on the row) and if the value is less than 20% then highlight. (which is the last part of the code):

This is what i have so far but i cant figure out how to solve it. I have to do this for work but i'm confused thanks!

```
Worksheets("Report").Activate
Call VBA

Dim lrow As Integer
Dim xrow As Integer

Dim FR As Range
Dim MR As Range
Dim cell As Range

lrow = wsr.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
xrow = wsr.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlToRight)

Set FR = Range("D12:D" & lrow)
For Each cell In FR
If cell.Value = "Cars" then for cell.xrow if cell.Value > 0.20 then Then cell.Interior.Color = RGB(224, 202, 224)
```

By Xrow i mean last cell on the row.

Thanks !

Comment: Last Cell on the row?  What column is that? or is it variable?

Comment: Try conditional formatting?

Comment: Just for a FYI: the Conditional formatting formula is `=AND($D12="Cars",INDEX(12:12,MATCH(1E+99,12:12))>0.2)`

Comment: @ScottCraner CF is a much better method IMHO but I couldn't quite get the 'last column' logic right in my attempt so went with VBA - you should post that as an answer, it's far better then mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
For Each cell In FR
    If cell.Value = "Cars" Then
        If Cells(cell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value < 0.2 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End If
Next
```

However Scott Craner's answer is a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid vba you can use Conditional Formatting.

The conditional formatting formula would then be:

```
=AND($D12="Cars",INDEX(12:12,MATCH(1E+99,12:12))>0.2)
```

The `INDEX(12:12,MATCH(1E+99,12:12))` part is what finds the last column in that row that has a number.  It then test whether it is greater than `.2`

You can apply it to all rows and columns desired to format starting with row 12, I only applied it to D12:D28:

[image]